# Access a Maven repository located in https

Tags: maven, https, ssl-certificate

I have a Maven project that requires some dependencies that are in a repository located behind HTTPS. I can access the URL by my browser (Firefox) as it asks me a username/password, but in Maven I get *Access denied*.

Where can I set the username and password so that Maven can use it for that repository? This [page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html) deals with certificates and keystores, but I don't have anything like that. Do I need to know where does Firefox stores the certificate for the URL I visited?

Comment: Version of maven? Wagon plugin and version in use?

Comment: It's on Windows, Maven 3.0.3, and there isn't any particular plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Username and password is stored into your .m2/ folder in a file called settings.xml (create it if you don't have it).

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <!-- this id should match the id of the repo server in pom.xml -->
            <id>myrepo</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
   </servers>
</settings>
```

For the second question, it's actually explained in the link you provided, except the keytool link is not working. If I remember right it was posted by a Sun employee in his blog and when Oracle took over the page disappeared. There should be multiple copies of it around the net. One of them is my slightly modified version on GitHub:

https://github.com/stivlo/obliquid-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/org/obliquid/scripts/InstallCert.java

The basic concept is that you don't have to find where Firefox stores the certificates, you download it with the tool in a file.

Comment: Setting the username and pass in the settings.xml file as you described did the trick. I didn't even need to deal with the certificates. Thanks for the quick response.